# Playing audio does not work in cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, audio, iframe

```
<script>
 var audio = new Audio('/static/notification.mp3');
 audio.play();
</script>
```

I have this in `domain.com:8080`. I am embedding this in an iframe the same domain but on `domain.com`.

The problem is, the audio doesn't play from within the iframe but when I go to `domain.com:8080` directly, the sound works perfectly.

So my understanding is `audio.play();` does not work in cross domain iframe. What is the solution, because I hear sounds playing in iframes across domains all the time.

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer:

just add

```
<script>
    document.domain = 'domain.com';
</script>
```

to both the parent and the iframe.

*source: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls*